# How to achieve optional selection in regular expressions?

Tags: regex

I have regular expression:

```
(?<message>.*)[\.](?:[\s]id:(?<id>.*)[\.])? code:(?<code>.*)[\.]
```

I have 2 cases for input text:

```
1. Failed to send sms. code:5063.
2. Failed to send sms. id:23. code:5063.
```

For the 1st case I want to have output like this:

```
1. Group message: Failed to send sms
2. Group code: 5063
```

For the 2nd case I want to have output like this:

```
1. Group message: Failed to send sms
2. Group id: 23
3. Group code: 5063
```

For the 1st case it's ok, but for the 2nd case I have:

```
1. Group Message: Failed to send sms. id:23
2. Group Code: 5063
```

It concatenates message and id. I can't understand why this is happening.

You can check it in the online editor here: https://regex101.com/r/bOWjKY/1/

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*` on the `message` part of regex is greedy. Add a `?` to make it stop at the first occurance.

```
(?<message>.*?)[\.](?:[\s]id:(?<id>.*)[\.])? code:(?<code>.*)[\.]
                 ^
```

https://regex101.com/r/bOWjKY/2/

alternatively you could use `U` modifier which inverts (ungreedy) behavior.

```
(?U)(?<Message>.*)[\.](?:[\s]id:(?<id>.*)[\.])? Code:(?<Code>.*)[\.]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's really help me. I spent ton of hours to understand. You are my angel of mercy!